# Convergence of $(b_n)$ if $b=b_0.b_1b_2...b_n...$

Tags: real-analysis, decimal-expansion

Suppose one has a decimal expansion of a real number $b:$ $$b=b_0.b_1b_2b_3...b_n...$$

where $b_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $0\leq b_n\leq9$ for $n\geq1$.

For which $b$ does $(b_n)$ converge?

Is the answer just real numbers that have period $0$ or $1$ decimal representations?

The idea behind this being since for $(b_n)$ to converge to $L$, we need, $\forall\epsilon>0, $ $|b_n-L|<\epsilon$ for $n$ greater than some $N\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $b_n$ consists of positive integer singletons, we need the sequence $(b_n)$ to be eventually constant; else, take $\epsilon:=\min\big\{\frac{b_i-b_j}{2}:0\leq i,j\leq9\big\}$. Then, no matter now large $N$ is, $|b_n-L|>\epsilon$ $\implies$ $(b_n)$ diverges.

Thus, so long as $b$ has a terminating decimal or eventually constant (one can view a terminating decimal as having infinitely many zeros at the end...) decimal expansion $(b_n)$, $(b_n)$ will converge.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: There is a different description of the answer, not exactly simpler, perhaps you can characterise the numbers $0.111\dots,0.222\dots,\dots$ and generalise

Comment: @CalvinKhor Hm. Do you mean, $1/9=0.111..., 2/ 9=0.222..., 3/9=1/3=0.333...$?

Comment: I originally posted an answer that presumed that the OP was constructing the sequence where $a_n = b_0 + \frac{b_1}{10} + \frac{b_2}{10^2} + \cdots + \frac{b_n}{10^n}.$  Apparently, I have misinterpreted the OP's intent, which was to (instead) focus on the sequence where $a_n = b_n.$  Therefore, I have deleted my answer.

Comment: @upanddownintegrate Yes

Comment: @CalvinKhor Those are also the types of numbers I had in mind. $1/12=0.83333...$ and $1/10=0.1000...$ fit the bill, too.

Comment: @upanddownintegrate indeed, and hence why I said to generalise. In the end the description will be longer in words, but arguably more 'concrete'. Not sure if it is better

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you, I will think on it :)

Comment: @CalvinKhor Ahhhh, I see. $1/90=0.0111...,1/900=0.00111...,$ etc. This will construct any arbitrary eventually periodic decimal expansion.

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely right that the eventually you need $b_n = b_{n+1} = \cdots$ since each $b_n$ can only be selected from $0,1,\cdots,9$. So either you're repeating $0$'s or repeating one of $1$ through $9$'s.

Lets assume for simplicity that $b_0 = 0$.

If you're repeating $0$'s, then $b = \frac{N}{10^n}$ for some $N <10^n$ and $n$ is the last nonzero digit.

If you're repeating $k$'s for $k \in \{ 1 \cdots 9\}$, then $b = \frac{N}{10^n} + \frac{k}{9 \times 10^{n}}$ where $n$ is the last nonrepeating digit.

For example, $0.58777777... = \frac{58}{100} + \frac{7}{900}$.

Note that this does not guarantee that $\frac{N}{10^n}$ or $\frac{k}{9 \times 10^{n}}$ can't be simplified further.

So, you could write $(b_n)$ converges if and only if there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $N \in \mathbb{N}_0$ satisfying $N<10^n $, and $k \in \{0,
\cdots 9\}$ such that $b - b_0 = \frac{N}{10^n} + \frac{k}{9 \times 10^{n}}$ .

Comment: If $n$ is the last repeating nonrepeating digit, doesn't that mean $b = \frac{N}{10^n} + \frac{k}{9 \times 10^{n+1}}$, for some $k\in\{1,2,...,9\}$?